# Haskell *** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse

Tags: parsing, haskell, parse-error

Hi I am trying to complete CIS194 Spring 13 when I get the error message `*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse` on one of my functions. The file that the function is in is called `LogAnalysis.hs` and the function is `parseMessage`, but the file also imports from `Log.hs`. Why am I geting this error message and how can I fix it?

Here is my code:
https://github.com/Adam-Morris/CIS194/tree/master/Homework-2

Answer (score 4):

`read` is a function with type `read :: Read a => String -> a`. This means that `read` takes `String` as input and returns a value for some type `a` provided that `a` implements the `Read` type class. `read` has to know what specific type to return, and it can know that in one of two ways: either the type is given to it explicitly (e.g. `read "123" :: Int` or `read "True" :: Bool`) or it infers it from the context. In your case, `read` infers that it must return an `Int` because `LogMessage` expects an `Int` as its second parameter. So in this case the expression `read [y]` means: take the `Char` `y`, convert it into an one-element string, and then try to convert that to an `Int`, by parsing it. Now if `y` happens to contain a character that is not a decimal digit, it will fail (by throwing an exception) because it will not know how to covert it into an integer.

Now how can you deal with that issue? You must check that the input to `read` is ok before calling it. For example, you can check that `y` is a digit (using the [appropriate function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:isDigit)):

```
parseMessage (x:y:z)
  | x == 'I' && isDigit y = LogMessage Info (read [y]) (unwords [z])
  ...
```

Alternatively, you can use [readMaybe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe) from [Text.Read](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html) that is like `read` but it does not throw an exception if it fails, instead it returns a nothing value:

```
parseMessage (x:y:z)
  | x == 'I', Just n <- readMaybe [y] = LogMessage Info n (unwords [z])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your input message format. You're reading a line as a string, then matching on the characters in the string (since a string is type alias for `[Char]`).
In your `sample.log` the first line (`I 6 Completed armadillo processing`) would be passed in as a string to `parseMessage`, and the parameters will take the following values:

`x` = `'I'`

`y` = `' ' --single white space character`

`z` = `"6 Completed armadillo processing"`

`read` gets the white space character and throws `*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse`

In order to get the values, you could do the following:

```
    parseMessage :: String -> LogMessage
    parseMessage msg = 
      case words msg of
        "I":y:z -> LogMessage Info (read y :: TimeStamp) (unwords z)
        "W":y:z -> undefined
        "E":y:z -> undefined
        _       -> undefined
```

This way the first two valid words (`MessageType` and `TimeStamp` in this case) can be extracted easily.